# Hitting brick wall on Wallace family from Vermont?

Tags: research-methods, vermont

What can I do when I hit a brick wall on the Wallace line?

I found a great grandfather who was born in Vermont in 1800, but cannot find his parents.

Comment: Hi, Dale -- welcome to G&FH.SE.  Can you tell us more about what information you've already collected about your great-grandfather, and what you have searched for already?

Comment: Notes for other users unfamiliar with Vermont:  records from this period were kept at the town level (statewide registration began in 1857 and a centralized registry did not begin until 1919).[Vermont Vital Records](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Vermont_Vital_Records)